# How is it possible that dynamic components overwrite each other's states?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state-management

I have created dynamic Room components which are created based on a room object dispatched by Redux.

```
{
    rooms && rooms.map((room, index) => {
        const { name, temperature, humidity, timestamp } = room

        return (
            <Col key={index} xs={12} md={6}>
                <Room 
                    index={index}
                    name={name} 
                    temperature={temperature} 
                    humidity={humidity}
                />
            </Col>
        )
    })
}
```

The details of each room are mounted properly. I create a function to maintain 10 objects in an array. However, when the array is passed into Rechart, it seems that my components are updating on top of the same state.

```
class Room extends Component {
    linechart = () => {
        const { timestamp, temperature, humidity, name } = this.props
        const { chartData } = this.state

        if(chartData.length > 9) chartData.shift()
        chartData.push({
            name, 
            timestamp: moment(timestamp).format('mm:ss'), 
            temperature, 
            humidity})
    }
}
```

[image]

As you can see, the component details are displayed properly. However, the values of chartData are being stored in the same state, despite being unique components.

I ran the function with an interval of 1 second, and the logs show that the state is being updated in 0.5 second intervals. That means both `<Room/>` components are using the same `<LineChart/>` component.
Does anyone know how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Your chartData seems to be fed by your component state, and not your props.

Comment: `const { chartData } = this.state` should be `const { chartData } = Object.assign({}, this.state)`

Comment: I don't think the problem lies with the use of states. I used an interval of 1 second, and the logs show that the state is being updated in 0.5 second intervals. That means both components are using the same <LineChart/> component.

Comment: I think you’re not supposed to mutate state, like you’re doing with `chartData.shift()`.

Comment: the component Room has a state? If yes, why you are changing the chartData without use setState to store that? without setState, the render() not will be called to refresh the draw

Comment: I see. I looked up on how I should shift and push states, and based on the answers provided, they were using the approach I used to do so. What is the proper way of shifting objects into state arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to update items in an `array`, I'd recommend using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). Spread syntax works by shallow copying the array, which keeps a reference to the original array, but allows you to overwrite any [data types](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp) stored within it. This keeps the array immutable.

I'm not sure where you're getting your data from, but since you have a finite amount of `rooms`, then the array should already be structured like so:

```
data: [
   { 
     name: "Room1", 
     humidity: 11,
     tempature: 30, 
     timestamp: "Sat May 25 2019 22:23:06 GMT-0700",
   },
   { 
     name: "Room2", 
     humidity: 11,
     tempature: 25, 
     timestamp: "Sat May 25 2019 22:23:06 GMT-0700",
   },
   ...etc
]
```

Then you can simply store this to `state` and when needed [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array and update its properties with incoming data. However, this assumes incoming data contains all the `rooms`. If you just need to update a specific `room` within the `rooms` array, then you can compare an `id` (or something that uniquely identifies it) to an incoming new data `id`.

For example, a new update comes in, but it's only updating `Room1`, then we could do something like so..

**incoming data**

```
data: [
  { 
    name: "Room1", 
    humidity: 11,
    tempature: 30, 
    timestamp: "Sat May 25 2019 22:23:06 GMT-0700",
   }
];
```

**current data stored in `state` as "rooms"**

```
 this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState, // spread out any previous state not related to "rooms"
      rooms: prevState.rooms.map(room => { // map over "rooms" and pull out each "room" object
        return room.name === data[0].name // if the "room.name" matches incoming data's "name", then...
          ? { ...data[0] } // spread and overwrite it with incoming data
          : room; // else leave the "room" as is
      })
 }));
```

Using `array prototypes` like `pop` and `shift` mutate the original array stored within `state` and React doesn't handle mutations to its `state`. You can, however, `clone` the `room` array with [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) or simply create a new array instance and mutate this new instance with some array `prototype` functions, but you **must** then re-set this new instance array to `state` to overwrite the old array -- React handles this without a problem. It's just not as clean as the spread syntax.

---

**Working example includes both `spread syntax` and `Array.prototype` options with a `setInterval`**:

[image: Edit Updating Values Inside Array]

**Working example of randomly updating one item within an array by an `id` with a `setInterval`**:

[image: Edit Randomly Updating Values Inside Array By Id]

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. It seems the problem lied with how I mutated the states, where I shift() and pop() the states directly. My approach to overcome this issue was spreading the original state into another variable and mutating it, then setting the state in a similar fashion as how you've demonstrated.